# Tirar o os valores menores ou iguais a 500 dentro da lista - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Código:

```
acid_vit_lista = [100,500, 200, 230, 400, 500, 600, 700, 900, 2000, 1100]
acid_vit_dig = int(input('\nNumero de acidentes de transito: '))

res_acid = (acid_vit_lista[num_dig])# num_dig foi da lista anterior
soma_acid = res_acid + acid_vit_dig
print(soma_acid)

quant_vit = len(acid_vit_lista)
maior_acid = max(acid_vit_lista)
menor_acid = min(acid_vit_lista)
print(f'O maior índice de acidentes foi {maior_acid}, e o menor índice foi {menor_acid}')
```

Estou precisando pegar todos os números `menores ou iguais` a 500 e calcular a média. Como posso fazer isso?

Estou no começo da programação.

Desde já, agradeço pela vossa atenção!

Comment: Obter os valores menores ou iguais a 500: `lista_filtrada = filter(lambda x: x <= 500, acid_vit_lista)`, obter a média: `media = sum(lista_filtrada) / len(lista_filtrada) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso você tem que percorrer os valores da sua lista e, se for menor ou igual a 500 adicionar a uma segunda lista.

Depois, para fazer a média é só domar todos os valores da segunda lista e dividir pelo número de elementos. Mais ou menos assim:

```
acid_vit_lista = [100,500, 200, 230, 400, 500, 600, 700, 900, 2000, 1100]
segunda_lista = []
soma = 0

for x in acid_vit_lista:
    if x <= 500:
        segunda_lista.append(x)

for x in segunda_lista:
    soma += x
    
print(soma/len(segunda_lista))
```

Claro que você pode fazer isso tudo através da da lista original, sem a necessidade de criar a segunda, mas pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, uma segunda lista é o desejo, e talvez seja mais fácil já que está começando.

Da mesma forma a soma dos elementos para o cálculo da média também poderia ser feito dentro do primeiro `for`, mas fiz separado para facilitar a compreensão.

Creio que otimizar o código com as dicas que eu dei possa ser um bom exercício para você estudar.

P.S. Retirei o acento do nome da sua lista. Nunca use acentos em nome de variáveis.

Comment: Uma maneira *inline* de fazer isso é com a função `mean` do módulo `statistics` assim: `statistics.mean(filter(lambda x: x <= 500, acid_vit_lista))`.

Comment: Obrigado Evilmaax! Ajudou muito! Valew!

Comment: Blz! Fiz o que pediu, mas diz que não aparece de forma pública. Mas valeu mesmo!

Answer (score 5):

Se existe a necessidade de gerar uma nova lista (e, dada a semântica do problema eu acho válido), o melhor é utilizar a compreensão de listas (ou *list comprehension*).

```
numbers = [100,500, 200, 230, 400, 500, 600, 700, 900, 2000, 1100]
numbers_ge_500 = [number for number in numbers if number >= 500]
```

Assim, basicamente você cria uma nova lista apenas com os valores de `numbers` que são maiores ou iguais a 500. Para calcular a média basta calcular a soma dividindo pela quantidade de números:

```
media = sum(numbers_ge_500) / len(numbers_ge_500)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja implementar um algoritmo que pegue todos os valores `menores ou iguais` a 500 de uma determinada lista e calcule sua [Média Aritmética](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/matematica/media-aritmetica.htm).

Pois bem, você **não precisa criar outra lista**. Basta você percorrer a lista original através de um laço de repetição `for` e verificar se cada item da respectiva interação é `menor ou igual` a 500. Caso positivo, contamos as vezes que tais valores aparecem na lista - variável `cont` - e acumulamos os valores de tais variáveis na variável `soma`. Em seguida, calculamos o quociente entre `soma` e `cont`.

Dessa forma, o algoritmo ficaria:

```
acid_vit_lista = [100, 500, 200, 230, 400, 500, 600, 700, 900, 2000, 1100]

cont = soma = 0
for item in acid_vit_lista:
    if item <= 500:
        cont += 1
        soma += item

media = (soma / cont)
print(f'\033[32mA media aritmética é: {media:.2f}')
```

Observe que este algoritmo percorre a lista `acid_vit_lista` e verifica se cada item da lista é `menor ou igual` a `500`. Caso positivo, acumula a **quantidade** de ocorrências na variável `cont` e acumula o **valor** de cada ocorrência na variável `soma`.

Em seguida, calcula a `média aritmética` dos respectivos valores e, posteriormente, exibe o valor com `duas` casas decimais.

**Observação**

A média aritmética entre `N` valores é **o quociente entre a soma dos valores e a quantidade de valores**, isto é, a variável `"soma"` dividida pela variável `"cont"`.

Agora se você deseja generalizar este algoritmo para calcular a média aritmética de todos os valores `menores ou iguais` a `500` de uma **lista qualquer**, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
acid_vit_lista = list(map(int, input('Digite o número de acidentes de trânsito: ').split()))

cont = soma = 0
for item in acid_vit_lista:
    if item <= 500:
        cont += 1
        soma += item

media = (soma / cont)
print(f'\033[32mA media aritmética é: {media:.2f}')
```

Quando executamos o segundo algoritmo recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite o número de acidentes de trânsito:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`. A partir desse momento o algoritmo calculará a média aritmética dos valores `menores ou iguais` a `500`.

**Qual a diferença entre o primeiro e segundo algoritmo?**

O primeiro algoritmo é capaz de trabalhar com apenas uma só lista, ou seja, a lista que foi previamente escrita no algoritmo. Já o segundo algoritmo, é capaz de trabalhar com um número indefinido de listas. Neste segundo algoritmo, a cada execução do mesmo, podemos digitar valores diferentes para montar a referida lista.

Comment: Muito boa a sua explicação. Estou começando nessa. Obrigado!